# WMF files no longer recognised; cannot work with them in GIMP

Tags: 12.04, gimp, conversion, eps

Back in 8.04 and 10.04, GIMP could easily open WMF files, letting me work on them.

In 11.04, there was a regression (still not fixed!), and this would not work.

But at least there was a workaround. You could convert WMF files to EPS and work on them.

```
wmf2eps --wmf-fontdir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts -o outputfile.eps inputfile.wmf
```

However, now we have 12.04, and not even the workaround works any more; it is unable to convert the file. There is no error message; it just fails with error code 1.

Despite Inkscapes claims to be a plausible solution (workaround) Inkscape simply opened the WMF image as a completely empty image, with no error message.

I need to work on WMF files quite urgently. Does anyone know what I can do, whether work-around or (preferably) a fix?

Comment: Did you add new plugins?

Comment: bebojoor I have only seen your comment now. Can you be specific about what you mean? I have installed gimp-data-extras. Today, I tested in a virtual machine, and it worked fine in 10.04; but by 10.10 it had stopped working. Same installation process -- fully update and install just ubuntu-restricted-extras, gimp, and gimp-data-extras. (So, the work-around is to run 10.04 in a virtual machine! What happens after 10.04 is no longer supported?)

Comment: This was probably an issue with libwmf, the library that is used by GIMP and other applications (wmf2eps) to read WMF files. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwmf/+bug/629153 seems to support that idea.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher — I no longer seem to have this problem, with most WMF files at any rate; there are still a few that I cannot open. I am sure that you're right, as I marked that bug as something that affects me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **Inkscape**

Inkscape's import for WMF is quite mature, and most WMF files can be imported without issues. You will have the ability to convert WMF file with something that is compatible with GIMP

You can download it from the **Ubuntu Software Center**

[Click here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FileTypes) for more information on Inkscape Wiki

**How to in Inkscape**

> Press the "File" option on the top navigation bar in Inkscape and
>   click "Import."
>
> A file navigation window opens.
>
> Click the drop-down box near the bottom of the page and select the
>   "Windows MetaFile (.wmf)" option.
>
> Navigate to and click on the WMF file using the file navigator.
>
> Click the "Open" button. The WMF file imports into and opens in
>   Inkscape.

**To Convert Try This**

> Click the "File" option from the top navigation bar and then click
>   "Save As."
>
> Click the "File Type" drop-down box and select another graphic file
>   type from the list.
>
> For example, to convert the WMF file to a PNG, click the "PNG (.png)"
>   option on the File Type list.
>
> Click the "Save" button. Note that you can also "Export" the WMF file
>   for even more graphic file options.
>
> Just click "Export" from the "File" menu instead of "Save As." Select
>   another graphic file type.
>
> Inkscape exports WMF files to the JPG or GIF file types.

Read more: How to Convert to WMF Graphics in Ubuntu | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_8693491_convert-wmf-graphics-ubuntu.html#ixzz1v1FJSTOc

Comment: Unfortunately, Inkscape did not work on 11.04 and still does not work on 12.04. Inkscape simply opened the WMF image as a completely empty image, with no error message.

Comment: I am not sure what method you used to open the file in Inkscape but i did a bit more research and updated my answer above.  If this is not the method you used, it will do no harm to try it.  If it was "Ce La vie"

Comment: Thanks for trying, Stephen, but I get the same result. I don't think I tried Inkscape on 10.04 or 8.04, but reading other people's posts, they didn't have a problem then but have a problem now. This is a definite regression.

Comment: Lets not give up just yet, but I really think when you find a solution you should permanently convert all your wmf files.  I have just read an article see link below  (significantly paragraph 8).  The claim is that Open Office Draw can read WMF files and export them to JPGs.  Judging by the content of this article this is probably your last hope as WMF seems to be an aging (almost redunant) format.  Im keen to know if this works.  http://www.ehow.com/convert-wmf-files/

Comment: I have just checked, the option to export WMF files appears to be possible in Libre Ofice Draw also

Comment: I appreciate your time, Stephen. I had considered LibreOffice, but the WMF files that I receive are sometimes so large that LibreOffice crops off large segments of the picture. If it were a matter of just converting existing files, I could go to a Windows computer, convert them all and be done with it; but I edit a non-profit magazine, and receive WMF files regularly for inclusion. The real problem is not trying to find a work-around, but fixing the regression -- it used to work, and it works on several non-Ubuntu distributions, so it really should work on Ubuntu! Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I have raised a bug-report for this. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1001570